# Filter records from select query using select subquery result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one select query from which I get the result. I have one more table which has some records.
I want that my first query result set should filter the records which I am getting from the table.

**Main Select Query**

```
select ri.pkResourceItemsID,r.locationTimeZone,ss.minBookingPeriod,r.fkBusinessUnitID,r.fkLocationId,r.floor from tblResourceItems ri WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join Enterprise.tblRooms r WITH (NOLOCK) on ri.pkResourceItemsID=r.roomID
inner join tblBusinessUnit bu WITH (NOLOCK) on r.fkBusinessUnitID=bu.pkBusinessUnitID 
inner join tblSiteSetup ss WITH (NOLOCK) on bu.pkBusinessUnitID=ss.fkBusinessUnitID 
where ri.active=1 
and ri.fkResourceID=1 
and r.fkresourceId=1 
and r.deliveryPoint=0 
and bu.deployment=1 
and bu.selfSelectRoom=0 
and bu.active=1 
and r.locationTimeZone = 'India Standard Time'
```

**Result**

[image]

**Second Table**

```
Select fkCondecoRoomID from SYNC.tblExternalRoomMaster where Active=1
```

**Result**

[image]

I have added the AND statement to filter the table result but it gives me an error.

```
and ri.pkResourceItemsID = (Select fkCondecoRoomID from SYNC.tblExternalRoomMaster where Active=1)
```

**Error**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, what about it don't you understand and we can try to elaborate. Also, why are you spamming the `NOLOCK` hint against *every* table? If you *really* "need" to use it against every table, then change the isolation level of the batch, but I suggest reading [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). (With respect, I doubt you do as someone well familiar with the query hint would understand the error you are getting.)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use `in` instead of `=` if the sub query can return more than 1 rows, which makes the last part query something like

```
and ri.pkResourceItemsID in (Select fkCondecoRoomID from SYNC.tblExternalRoomMaster where Active=1)
```

Comment: Hope you are not Updating/Inserting anything with this, the table corruption could be biblical.

WITH(NoLock) AKA - creating queries that are Sackable offences and that work like a random number generator.

Comment: @rAJ See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists